# Is there a way to make inference work with extended string in conditional typescript?

Tags: typescript, inference

I'm trying to extract a generic string literal type but typescript inference returns only the type string instead.

So technically once a string literal type passed to a function we cannot extract it anymore.

```
type Key<T extends string> = { key: T };

declare function getKey<T extends string>(key: T): Key<T>;

let someKey = getKey('check');

declare function updateWithKey<T, K extends string>(key: T): T extends Key<K> ? K : never;

let someUpdatedKey = updateWithKey(someKey); // Shouldn't be 'check'?
```

Here is the code in [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Key%3CT%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20key%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20getKey%3CT%20extends%20string%3E(key%3A%20T)%3A%20Key%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20someKey%20%3D%20getKey('check')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20updateWithKey%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20string%3E(key%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20extends%20Key%3CK%3E%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20someUpdatedKey%20%3D%20updateWithKey(someKey)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Shouldn't%20be%20'check'%3F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `updateWithKey`, `K` does not appear in a position where it can be automatically inferred by a compiler, so it's taken to be the most generic type allowed, that is, `string`.

But conditional types [have special syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to tell the compiler that you want actual type to be inferred:

```
type Key<T extends string> = { key: T };

declare function getKey<T extends string>(key: T): Key<T>;

let someKey = getKey('check');

declare function updateWithKey<T>(key: T): T extends Key<infer K> ? K : never;

let someUpdatedKey = updateWithKey(someKey); // let someUpdatedKey: "check"
```